# Ms Sql table to left join on Sybase table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sap-ase, mssql-jdbc

Can anyone give me an idea on how to select from a table in another database? For example, in my **MS SQL database** I have a table named `employee`, and I want to create a query to **left join** on a **Sybase database** table `employee`.

Comment: You can BCP out the table out from one server and BCP in into other server.

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked server on your ms sql server to the Sybase db.  Write a stored procedure in sql server that:

1. Creates a temporary table
2. Uses openquery to populate the temp table from the Sybase db
3. Runs a select query that left joins the sql server table to the temporary table.

Comment: How to openquery from ms sql to sybase ? Thank you

Comment: Once you have your linked server set up, it's select * from openquery (linkedServerName, 'select query goes here').  Note that the server name is not quoted but the sql is.